# 8 displayed as 9 - strange visual glitch - cell formatted as fraction

Tags: google-sheets, floating-point, number-formatting, google-sheets-formula

The displayed value is different from the actual one. To reproduce enter:
`=8+1/5-1/5`

In any cell and then format it as `# ?/?`. To do that go to:

*Format -> Number -> More Formats -> Custom number format*

And choose `# ?/?`(or enter it in the textbox if it is not in the list).

Result:

[image]

(in `B1` the formula is `A1=8`)

I could not find any other number than 8 (1-250) exposing such a strange behavior. I could not replicate same bug with constants like `7.9999999999` or `8.000000001`.

Wrapping the formula with `ROUND` (`=ROUND(8+1/5-1/5,307)`) fixes the problem.

So this looks like a bug (where to report that?).

But the main question is: is there something special about this simple formula in floating point maths to confuse the interpreter?

PS: this bug cannot be reproduced in Excel 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like it's rounded up, but like this it's correct:

[image: 0]

you can report it like this:

[image: 0]

[image]